# Can I keep a PowerShell script from deleting moved and cut files?

Tags: powershell, scripting

My need is to delete all files older than 14 days in a public folder. I have cobbled together a PowerShell script that just about does the trick as I need it. . . The only problem is, if the user moves a file into the folder - as opposed to copying it - my script will delete that file if it was last accessed more than 14 days ago, even if it was moved into the public folder the same day. The same thing happens with cut and paste. So this is a pretty serious problem.

Here is my script:

```
# Delete all files older than "file_age" days, at "path".
$path = "C:\Users\emcguire\Desktop\Test"
$file_age = "-14"

$current_date = Get-Date
$date_to_delete = $current_date.AddDays($file_age)

Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -lt $date_to_delete } | Remove-Item
```

I am pretty new to PowerShell, so I may be missing something very obvious. Is there an easy way to check for files that were moved into the folder but do not have their access timestamp changed? Is there a better way to approach this?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't think you can do anything about this in your script. It sounds like it's working as designed. The date you're relying on isn't being updated in certain situations, so you either need to restrict those situations, or use different criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `LastAccessTime` is a notoriously avoided property.  Try to use `LastWriteTime` where ever possible first.  Additionally, all those properties are stale, meaning they aren't refreshed when you call them.  Use this code to call the refresh method to guarantee you've got the fresh file system info before you query the property:

```
$file = c:\somefile.txt
$fileObj = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $file
$fileObj.Refresh()
```

As you're wanting to base your actions off of how long the file has been in the archive directory, you may want to value you the `CreationTime` attribute.  I added a link below to the list of what your choices are in case there's a better one for your needs.

[For reference on the refresh method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)

[For reference on properties to value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Can I call the refresh method for an entire folder, or will I need to loop through all the files in that folder and call the refresh method on each one?

Comment: You'll need to loop through the files and call the refresh on each one.  The refresh is specific to the file object instance, unfortunately.

Comment: This still causes any files moved or cut-and-pasted into the folder - say one day ago - to sometimes be deleted, when they had not been modified, etc., in their old location. Maybe I need to approach solving this issue in a different way?

Comment: Possibly the `CreationTime` is better suited to your needs.  I've updated my answer.